# Concatenate / simplify RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I've this working RegExp in my JavaScript file:

```
var reA = new RegExp(urlValueToRemove);
var reB = new RegExp('(,&)');
var reC = new RegExp('(,,)');
var reD = new RegExp('(=,)');
var reE = new RegExp('(,$)');

window.history.pushState(null, null, decodeURIComponent(window.location.search).replace(reA, '').replace(reB, '&').replace(reC, ',').replace(reD, '=').replace(reE, ''));
```

Is it possible to concatenate / simplify this so that I don't need to do the `replace` 5 times?

I've asked this in the codereview community but there is nobody available so I think I must need to wait days there.

**Example**

When I have this URL here:

> http://localhost.com/?color=Red,Blue,Green&size=X,L,M,S

When I want to remove now the `Green` from the URL I can pass `Green` to the first Regex `reA` and it gets removed from the URL:

> http://localhost.com/?color=Red,Blue&size=X,L,M,S

Comment: I think this question would be better on [**https://codereview.stackexchange.com/**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since it doesn't have a specific problem. You are asking how to improve fully functioning source code which codereview is for.

Comment: @NewToJS Alright I'll ask it there. I never saw this page :)

Comment: @NewToJS I've asked there but there is nobody. So I'll leave it here if it's okay.

Comment: What is  `filter_value`?

Comment: @trincot It's a variable with a string in it. Forgot to replace it for the question.

Comment: @Mr.Jo It is fine to leave it here but you might find some people will downvote it  since this isn't really suitable for stackoverflow. I myself will not be down voting as I find it interesting but in the wrong place. If you do get a solution please share here too if you keep this post open. Thank you.

Comment: @NewToJS Alright. I'll do this. I'm currently trying to concat it but I'm not sure if it works after that. Maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: If you post your attempt to contact it that would then make this question suitable if the outcome isn't what you are expecting but it would require you to then explain your expected output and possibly provide a working example of what you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the capture group to indicate what should be kept, and join the two cases with a `|`: one case needs to keep the character that *precedes* the word (like `=`), the other what *follows* the word (like `&`):

```js
function removeWord(url, text) {
    const re = new RegExp(`,${text}(&|,|$)|(=)${text},`, 'g');
    return url.replace(re, '$1$2');
}

const url = "http://localhost.com/?color=Red,Blue,Green&size=X,L,M,S"
console.log(removeWord(url, "Green"));
```

Comment: This don't made it. I'll leave it as it is because it' working that way. When I found a better solution I'll answer it here.

Comment: Could you explain for which input this solution is not giving the output you expect?

Comment: I've added a solution to my question.

Comment: Could you please provide the expected output for the example you have given. Give the *literal* expected value from that.

Comment: I've added the output of the URL after the RegExp thing

Comment: Great. Now I see what you are looking for. See update of my answer.